# How to find out where a previously lost brick fits?

Tags: set-database, part-database, bricklink-studio

Rebrickable manages a list of lost parts. If I later find one of these, I have to go through the PDF of instructions to put it back where it belongs, which can be tedious. Does someone know if there is a database of searchable instructions to directly get to the right page? Or better yet: instructions for commercial sets in a format similar to the one used by Bricklink Stud.io?